Show +1 in mat-chip-list within the mentioned width when more items are present
I'm looking for the solution for the above mention issue. When the angular chiplist has more item within the mentioned width, The reamianing elements has to be displayed as a numbers of items present.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks In advance
Same as the post How to show ellipsis on mat-chip-list when more chips are present but number should also be part of chiplist
